# Cannot assign CTE result to a varchar variable?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I am trying to write the following SQL.

```
declare @s varchar(max) = (
  with c as (select ...)
  select a, b, c, d, ....
  from ... join c on .... join c on .... join c on ....
  order by ...
  for xml raw('...'), elements
);
```

However, it's incorrect syntax (The following shows the error message). Do I have to convert it to subqueries? I am trying to avoid to expand the CTE in multiple places.

> Incorrect syntax near the keyword 'with'. If this statement is a common table expression, an xmlnamespaces clause or a change tracking context clause, the previous statement must be terminated with a semicolon.

**Update:**
The `for xml` and `order by` makes `select @s = ...`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, I figured it out. It cannot be done in one declare and initialization statement.

```
declare @s varchar(max);

with c as (select 1 a union all select 2 union all select 3)
, x(s) as (select a from c order by a desc for xml raw('tr'), elements)
select @s = s from x
```

Comment: @Abe - _"the secret to originality is to forget the source"_ +1 to your answer.

Answer (score 12):

You need to separate the declaration of `@s` from the assignment.

Something like this will work for you.

```
declare @T table
(
  ID int,
  Col1 int
)

insert into @T values(1, 10),(2, 20)

declare @s varchar(max)

;with C as
(
  select *
  from @T
)
select @s = 
  (
    select *
    from C as C1
      inner join C as C2
        on C1.ID = C2.ID
    for xml raw, elements
  )

select @s
```

Result:

```
<row>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Col1>10</Col1>
  <ID>1</ID>
  <Col1>10</Col1>
</row>
<row>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Col1>20</Col1>
  <ID>2</ID>
  <Col1>20</Col1>
</row>
```

Answer (score 7):

I think it's just the way you are trying to assign the value.  Try using the following method instead:

```
declare @s varchar(max);
with temp as
(
   select ....
  from ... join c on .... join c on .... join c on ....
  for xml raw('...'), elements
)
select @s = value from temp
select @s
```

As the error message states, your real issue is that the statement before your CTE is not terminated with a `;` which is a requirement when using a CTE.

I ran the above with`select 'test' as value` defining the CTE instead of your query and it worked as expected.

Comment: The `for xml` probably makes it not feasible?

Comment: I'm not sure.  I'm not able to test it at the moment.  I would recommend trying the method I provided above.  The error you were getting doesn't seem to be related to the use of `for xml`...

Comment: "When a CTE is used in a statement that is part of a batch, the statement before it must be followed by a semicolon."

Comment: `with temp as (select ... for xml...)` needs to be changed to `with c as (...), temp(value) as (...)`.

Comment: Could someone please explain to me why `SELECT @s =` works, but `SET @s =` does not?